# How to make scikit-learn Nearest Neighbors algorithm run faster?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, recommendation-engine

I am trying to run a text-based recommendation system to find the category of a part from a file of about 56K parts:
Eg: Copper tube -> Wire,
    Television  -> Electronics etc

However, it's taking about 4 hours for getting the recommender system output when running in my system of 8GB RAM. I tried running the same script on a ram about 32 GB but there is no improvement in the computation time, which is still taking 4 hours. The training set for the recommender system is about 11k.

How can I make my recommender system run faster? It seems the script is not making use of the memory effectively. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

NB: The example shown is just for illustration and the original data set is much more complicated.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

#Code for recommendation system
def recommendhts(x,model,train):
    distance,index=model.kneighbors(x.toarray(),n_neighbors=1)
    mi=distance.argmax()
    idx=index[mi][0]
    return(train.iloc[idx]['sHTS'],distance[0][0])

#Training the model of training set
train=pd.read_csv('train0207190144.csv')
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['keywords'])
x=X.toarray()
df=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
model=NearestNeighbors(metric='correlation',n_neighbors=1)
model.fit(df)
vect=vectorizer.fit(train['keywords'])

#Fitting the Count vectoriser on keywords(product description to be queried)

x_new=vect.transform(product['keywords'])

for i in range(len(product)):
    key=x_new[i]
    output,probability=recommendhts(key,model,train)
```

Edit:
I am attaching the snapshot of the result of profiling [Code profiling results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MAiM.png) as suggested in the comments. I ran it for a sample of 1000 rows and the time taken was about 1085 seconds.

Comment: I recommend doing some profiling to figure out where you're spending all your time. If you find that the time is concentrated in one place, it's easier to make a recommendation. It's possible you're spending most of your time in sci-kit learn, in which case, you may be limited for what you can do to improve time in your code.

Comment: How large is the training data set?

Comment: @davidrpugh The training set is about 11,000. The problem is whether I run it in 8GB system or 32 GB system, there is no difference in the computation time.

Comment: @fiveclubs Thanks for the reply I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Fact that computation time is not impacted by adding more memory suggests that compute and not memory is the binding constraint.

Answer (score 0):

First you definitely need to profile your code. I would recommend making use of the `%prun` magic command in IPython/Jupyter for [profiling your script](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html).

Couple of other things to try

1. Set the 'n_jobs' parameter to allow for parallelism when making predictions.

   ```
   # setting n_jobs=2 will use 2 cores; setting n_jobs=-1 will use all cores
   model=NearestNeighbors(metric='correlation',n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=2)
   ```
2. Unclear to me that re-fitting the `vectorizer` is necessary.

   ```
   vect=vectorizer.fit(train['keywords'])  # can be removed?
   ```

Finally, you should be able to vectorize the predictions and replace the `for` loop but this would require refactoring your recommendation system and I can not help with that without more info.

Comment: Hi David, 
Thanks for the suggestions. I tried profiling as suggested for a sample of 1000 rows and have attached the snapshot of the results in the original question.
I also tried setting 'n_jobs' to 2 but unfortunately, it worsened my performance. It is now taking about 90 mins for the same 1000 rows. I have also corrected the fitting of countvectoriser, but it didnt made any difference.

If you have any more suggestions, please let me know. It will help me a lot.